# How can i solve Capistrano command error, cap production deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash, capistrano

I am on windows machine while using the command line i get this error 
"(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks) cap aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/passenger C:/Sites/Buy/Capfile:23:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)"

And on git bash with the same command i have this error. 
" cap production deploy C:/tools/ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:235:in `bin_path': can't find gem capistrano ([">= 0.a"]) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/cap:22:in`'"

The gems i am using.

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'protected_attributes', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.3'

gem 'rake', '~> 10.5'

gem 'rake-compiler', '~> 0.9.5'

gem 'rspec', '~> 3.4'

gem 'omniauth-digitalocean', '~> 0.2.0'

gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.6'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 6.3', '>= 6.3.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'pg'

gem "cf-autoconfig", "~> 0.2.1"

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'

gem 'json', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.3'

gem 'omniauth-twitter', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'

gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 3.0'

platforms :ruby do

gem 'unicorn'

end

group :development do

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4'

gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'

gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.4'

gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same error but with:

```
capistrano/rbenv
```

I commit the line (in your case 23) in Gapfile and the deploy work with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may have included a line in `Capfile` that is:

```
require 'capistrano/passenger'
```

Please remove this line and try again `cap production deploy:initial`
The new capistrano requires the passenger file but I think you are not using passenger but webrick, puma or unicorn. So that is the reason your cap cannot find passenger.

For more info on deploying rails app to digital ocean ubuntu server with capistrano, puma, nginx complete tutorial available at:
http://sulmanbaig.com/blog/deploy-on-digitalocean-rails-puma-nginx